# Why is fileToString not reading the contents of the file properly?

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-3, geotagging

I was following the instructions for CLAVIN installation. When I tried to build the CLAVIN package, it would display a 'Build Failure' after the TextUtilsTest, which checks that the contents extracted from a file are exactly the same as an expected String. Here's the code of the [TEST](https://clavin.bericotechnologies.com/clavin-core/xref-test/com/bericotech/clavin/util/TextUtilsTest.html), and here's the [method that reads contents from file](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.bericotech/clavin/1.0.0rc7/com/bericotech/clavin/util/TextUtils.java). 
These are the details behind its failure:

```
<failure message="wrong output from fileToString expected:&lt;Line1 word2[&#10;Line2 word2 word3]&#10;Line3&gt; but was:&lt;Line1 word2[&#10;Line2 word2 word3&#13;]&#10;Line3&gt;" type="org.junit.ComparisonFailure"><![CDATA[org.junit.ComparisonFailure: wrong output from fileToString expected:<Line1 word2[
Line2 word2 word3]
Line3> but was:<Line1 word2[
Line2 word2 word3
]
Line3>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at com.bericotech.clavin.util.TextUtilsTest.testFileToString(TextUtilsTest.java:56)
]]></failure>
```

I checked the input file, and the contents are exactly the same as the provided string. I suspected that the problem is due to the encoding of the text file, I tried all other encodes, but it only made things worst. Would you suggest I ignore the exception, and move on to the next installation step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unexpected `&#13;` or CR, carriage return, `\r`. For the rest `&#10;` or LF, `\n` is used as newline. Now Windows uses `\r\n` as newline char, so maybe there is some mess of handing newlines. As a text area on Windows yielding a CR+LF containing text, where LFs were removed, and then pasted into a LF-only XML.

(The `&#13;` being a numeric entity for XML. Old MacOS had `\r` as newline.)

The solution is some line-ending replace of multi-line input text of merely `\n`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked after I've replaced all newline characters with a space.